# How to downgrade ADF Self-hosted Integration Runtime version?

Tags: azure-data-factory

It has been very unstable since latest Self-hosted IR version was installed to VM.
There has been activity timeouts and even temp offlines.

How to downgrade to previous version? Need to uninstall IR from VM first?

Comment: Yes, you need to uninstall the IR from VM without deleting the details of IR which is in Azure data factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created virtual machine in Azure portal.
I created azure data factory and created selfhosted integration run time.

image for reference:

[image]

I install the Microsoft integration run time 5.22.8312.1 in virtual machine and connected to azure data factory using keys.
Image for reference:

[image]

It is successfully connected to Azure data factory.
Image for reference:

[image]

I install the Microsoft integration run time 5.23.8324.1 in virtual machine without stopping the service of Microsoft integration run time 5.22.8312.1. upgraded version automatically connected to the integration runtime without entering key of runtime.
Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

I want to downgrade Integration runtime from 5.23.8324.1 version to 5.22.8312.1. for that I uninstall the 5.23.8324.1 uninstall the IR from VM without deleting the details of IR which is in Azure data factory.
Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

I reinstall the Microsoft integration runtime 5.22.8312.1 again in VM, its automatically connected to the data factory. IR is downgraded successfully.
Image for reference:

[image]